# Jquery fade out a div?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to show and hide two div positioned absolutely on top of each other. When one is opened the other closes.

```
function ShowHide(){
$("#info").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 300 });
$("#credits:visible").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 300 });
}
function ShowHide2(){
$("#credits").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 300 });
$("#info:visible").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 300 });
}
```

I want to fade the div's in rather than animate them, i substituted .animate with .fadeIn which worked fine but i cannot get the div to then fade out when the link in clicked again. I tried the .fadeOut method with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: This is a jquery question so everyone is going to swarm and you will get an answer, but if you post the html & css it will make life easier on those trying to help you and get you a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/):

```
function ShowHide() {
    $("#info, #credits:visible").fadeToggle(300);
}

function ShowHide2() {
    $("#credits, #info:visible").fadeToggle(300);
}
```

**EDIT:** As @FishBasketGordo correctly points out, if your elements are set up properly (one visible, the other hidden initially), then you only need one call (and one function):

```
$("#credits, #info").fadeToggle(300);
```

Comment: This is good, but you only need one call to `fadeToggle`: `$('#info, #credits').fadeToggle(1000);`